# Swift/iOS - Massive memory usage attributed to "__StringStorage"?

Tags: ios, swift, memory, profiling, heap-memory

I'm seeing huge memory usage in my app (almost a gig)

I profiled my app by generating and exporting a Memory Graph and ran

`heap -s --showSizes my_memgraph.memgraph`

I'm seeing hundreds of megabytes attributed to __StringStorage

```
    COUNT     BYTES       AVG   CLASS_NAME                                       TYPE    BINARY
    =====     =====       ===   ==========                                       ====    ======
       56      3584      64.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
    47279   3782320      80.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
       61      5856      96.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
        6       672     112.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
    21021   2690688     128.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
     1008    145152     144.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
    19030   3044800     160.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
        1       192     192.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
     6000   1536000     256.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
        5     12800    2560.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
     7052 231079936   32768.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
     7000 344064000   49152.0   __StringStorage                                  Swift   libswiftCore.dylib
   292889   4686224      16.0   non-object                                                                 
    92169   2949408      32.0   non-object                                                                 
    54659   2623632      48.0   non-object                                                                 
    72672   4651008      64.0   non-object
```

What is that and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I found the libswiftCore in the memgraph gui and clicking around on the objects noticed that nearly all of them were retained by GraphQL.

Changing the graphQL cache policy from `.fetchIgnoringCacheData` to `.fetchIgnoringCacheCompletely` made my problem go away.